# Unable to install/run any PowerShell packages

Tags: powershell

I'm receiving the error below anytime I try to install a PowerShell module.

`Install-Module: The 'Install-Module' command was found in the module 'PowerShellGet', but the module could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module PowerShellGet'.`

When I try and run Import-Module PowerShellGet per the error message I receive.
`Import-Module: The required module 'PackageManagement' is not loaded. Load the module or remove the module from 'RequiredModules' in the file`

I have already tried setting my execution policy to be unrestricted, reinstalled Windows, and changed PowerShell to TLS 1.2.

### PowerShell Version

5.1.19041.906

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this, from your cmd.exe as an administrator...

```
powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command 'Install-Module -Name PackageManagement -Force -MinimumVersion 1.4.6 -Scope CurrentUser -AllowClobber'
```

... then try what you are after again.

Answer (score 0):

PowerShellGet started working again after signing into a second account on my pc. Not sure why that worked, but I can't complain.